# Search membership queries in SCCM

Tags: sccm

More details on what we require:

We have a bunch of AD groups that may not be doing anything at all.    What we would ideally like to do is somehow search SCCM for any usage of a particular AD group.  Like if the group is used as part of a membership query anywhere.

For example I have tried the following in SCCM Powershell to look for any usage of the AD group sccm.minitablets :

```
Get-CMUserCollectionQueryMembershipRule | Where -Property RuleName -Like "%mini%"
```

I don't think the above command is of much use, as it has a required parameter that takes a specific collection name, whereas I need to search for any use of sccm.minitablets in any collection or any membership rule query across the board.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

Was able to find a solution to this, for anyone else who might be interested:

```
Get-CMUserCollection | Get-CMUserCollectionQueryMembershipRule | Where -Property QueryExpression -Like "*mini*"

Get-CMDeviceCollection | Get-CMDeviceCollectionQueryMembershipRule | Where -Property QueryExpression -Like "*mini*"
```